# What happened to the code formatting icon?

Tags: support, editing

The code formatting button seems to have disappeared in edit mode:

[image: screen shot]

(Firefox 4 on a Mac)

Comment: You mean the indent-by-4-spaces icon? It's the `{}` one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's there -- we normalized to

`{}`

as the code icon instead of

`010101`

See:
[Change icon of Code Sample button](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72509/change-icon-of-code-sample-button/72513#72513)

Comment: Duh.  Ok.   Thanks.

Comment: But I'm not imagining that it was the 10101 icon until just now on this site?

Comment: The new icon is remarkably suitable for this site in particular... We love curly braces...

Comment: @alan we changed it on the trilogy a while ago, and just now pushed it out to the rest of the network